# Compute $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)\operatorname{ch}(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}2)}$ with residue theorem

Tags: complex-numbers, residue-calculus

[image]

$$\frac1{\operatorname{ch}(\frac\pi2)}-\frac1{3\operatorname{ch}(\frac{3\pi}2)}+\frac1{5\operatorname{ch}(\frac{5\pi}2)}-\cdots$$

How can I sum the above series in the image with the residue theorem? I solved the first two but failed with the third for that $zf(z)$ does not converge to 0 at $|z|\to\infty$, making the hints(methods) in the second image seem unavailable.

[image]

The second formula in the second picture should not have a n on the left. The third and fourth formula requires that $zj$ are not semi-integer rather than integer.

Comment: Please make the question self-contained by writing up the actual series instead of linking to a picture.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{ch}(x)$? Is it equivalent to $\cosh x$?

Comment: ch(x) is just cosh(x)